# python3 super doesn't work with PyQt classes

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4, method-resolution-order

There is a simple program in python3:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore
import PyQt4

class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Bar start")
        super(Bar, self).__init__()
        print("Bar end")

class FakeQObject(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("FakeQObject start")
        super(FakeQObject, self).__init__()
        print("FakeQObject end")

class Foo(QtCore.QObject, Bar):
#class Foo(FakeQObject, Bar):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Foo start")
        super(Foo, self).__init__()
        print("Foo end")


print(Foo.__mro__)
print(PyQt4.QtCore.PYQT_VERSION_STR)
f = Foo()
```

a) When class Foo inherits from QtCore.QObject and Bar we get:

```
(<class '__main__.Foo'>, <class 'PyQt4.QtCore.QObject'>, <class 'sip.wrapper'>, <class 'sip.simplewrapper'>, <class '__main__.Bar'>, <class 'object'>)
4.9.4
Foo start
Foo end
```

b) When class Foo inherits from FakeQObject and Bar we get:

```
(<class '__main__.Foo'>, <class '__main__.FakeQObject'>, <class '__main__.Bar'>, <class 'object'>)
4.9.4
Foo start
FakeQObject start
Bar start
Bar end
FakeQObject end
Foo end
```

The question is: why in the a) case, Bar init is not called?

I found similar question here [pyQt4 and inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901178/pyqt4-and-inheritance) but there are no good answers.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suspect it is because `QtCore.QObject` doesn't use the cooperative super.`__init__`. BTW, in Python 3, you don't need `super(Foo, self)`; `super()` should be sufficient.

Comment: Yes, but PyQt site http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/gotchas.html says: "In versions of PyQt earlier than v4.5 there were restrictions on the use of super with PyQt classes. These restrictions no longer apply with v4.5 and later." So, this is a bug of PyQt, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks for super() without params, didn't know about it..

Comment: Is there a reason you can't move `Bar` before `QObject` in the inheritance order?

Comment: In my project I already did so.. But It's unnatural and sad, that limitations of language/library/whatever dictate application design.

Comment: Note that this is not a limitation of PyQt4 and/or Python3: the same behaviour will occur with PySide, and with Python2.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem: In Py3k no need to explicitly derive from `object`. You can omit `object` as it is the default. Your print of `__mro__` won't change. Saves typing and confusion. Keep `(object)` only for scripts that need to run in both Py2 and Py3. Doesn't address your question, though :-/

Answer (score 3):

Along with @nneonneo I also suspect that `QtCore.QObject` doesn't use the cooperative `super.__init__`.  If it did, you wouldn't have this problem.

However, you should be aware that at some point one of the base classes *cannot* use cooperative super because `object` won't have the method.  Consider:

```
class Base():
    def __init__(self):
        print("initializing Base")
        super().__init__()
    def helper(self, text):
        print("Base helper")
        text = super().helper(text)
        text = text.title()
        print(text)

class EndOfTheLine():
    def __init__(self):
        print("initializing EOTL")
        super().__init__()
    def helper(self, text):
        print("EOTL helper")
        text = super().helper(text)
        return reversed(text)

class FurtherDown(Base, EndOfTheLine):
    def __init__(self):
        print("initializing FD")
        super().__init__()
    def helper(self, text):
        print(super().helper(text))

test = FurtherDown()
print(test.helper('test 1 2 3... test 1 2 3'))
```

and the output:

```
initializing FD
initializing Base
initializing EOTL
Base helper
EOTL helper
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 28, in <module>
    print(test.helper('test 1 2 3... test 1 2 3'))
  File "test.py", line 25, in helper
    print(super().helper(text))
  File "test.py", line 7, in helper
    text = super().helper(text)
  File "test.py", line 17, in helper
    text = super().helper(text)
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'helper'
```

So, whichever class is going to be the End of the Line needs to not call `super`.  Because there are other `Qt` methods you might want to override, that dictates that the `Qt` class must be the last one in the class header.  By not having `__init__` use cooperative super, even though it could, `Qt` is avoiding bugs further down when some other method is overridden.