# Python error "TypeError: could not convert X to Y" in multiple inheritance

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, multiple-inheritance, typeerror

I've translated in Python/PyQt a code that was working fine in C++/Qt and I don't understand why it now generates an error. Here is a minimal code reproducing the problem:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class A(QFrame): 
    def __init__(self, parent) :
        QFrame.__init__(self, parent)    


class B(A, QLine):
    def __init__(self, parent) :
        A.__init__(self, parent)
        QLine.__init__(self, parent)

class C(B):

    def __init__(self, parent) :
        B.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setLine(0, 0, 0, 0)



if __name__ == "__main__":

    app     = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myApp   = QMainWindow()
    myApp.show()

    c = C(myApp)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When running this code, I get the message "TypeError: could not convert 'C' to 'QLine'"... Why is that so? What is the problem? How to get around?

Comment: I don't actually know whether this is your problem, but… it's usually better to use `super` than to try to figure out the MRO explicitly like this.

Comment: Also… why do you want something that is-a frame and also is-a line? That seems like an odd thing to be…

Comment: @abarnert It seems it has nothing to do with MRO. Your answer bellow seems to pinpoint the true problem. For many reasons, I prefer not to use the super here (in fact, in the actual code which the minimal version reproduces). As for why inheriting both QLine and QFrame, it is because C must be of the same type as A (for practical reasons not showing in this minimal version) but it also has to draw as a line. Might not seems obvious in this minimal version of the code but it does work well in C++ although it fail here in PyQT because of multiple inheritance on QObject. Thank you.

Comment: First, does `C` really need to be the same type as `A(QFrame)`? Or can you extract the non-frame part of `A` out into a mixin that both `C` and `A` inherit from? That would solve your problem.

Comment: Second, as I understand it, it _doesn't_ work in C++; you happen to get away with it here because you're not making any use of the `QFrame` members or vtable in `C`. And that's why PyQt bans it: it's dangerous and fragile, and situations where it's actually useful are rare. But I could be understanding wrong.

Comment: @abarnert Maybe I've just been lucky and it would have failed latter, but I did not encounter any problems with my C++ version. As for your suggestion about QFrame, I really need A to inherit QFrame (in the complete version of the code) so I just reimplemented a Line object to drop QLine. I really just needed an object representing conceptually a line and I took QLine because it saved me writing some lines of code. But it's not a big deal implementing such an object... As a matter a fact, I'm done implementing it and it now works just fine. Thankx again.

Comment: That's a good point; there's really no reason something with the `QLine` interface even needs to be a `QObject`, is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [various](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351976/python3-super-doesnt-work-with-pyqt-classes) [other](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2011-April/029695.html) [posts](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-928048-start-0.html), you cannot inherit from `QObject` twice.

They all link to http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/gotchas.html#multiple-inheritance, which I can no longer find. But [Things to be Aware Of](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/gotchas.html#multiple-inheritance) in the PyQt 4.10.2 Reference Guide says:

> It is not possible to define a new Python class that sub-classes from more than one Qt class.

Quoting one of the answers:

> The limitation doesn't come from python or PyQt. Its purely because of Qt and 
>   means that you can not inherit from multiple classes that are or inherit from 
>   QObject.

According to other answers, it's apparently not that it's *impossible* in Qt, it's that it doesn't do what you expect in C++ unless you use virtual inheritance (which causes *other* problems with Qt), so PyQt4 blocks it. In particular, in your example, `C` isn't really properly a `QFrame`, but as long as you never use any `QFrame` virtual methods, or any functions that depend on members that `QFrame` inherited from `QObject`, you will happen to get away with it.

---

Anyway, there seems like an obvious workaround here. What you need is "C must be of the same type as A (for practical reasons)". You can get that by splitting `A` up:

```
class AMixin(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        pass
    # A-specific behavior

class A(QFrame, AMixin):
    def __init__(self, parent) :
        QFrame.__init__(self, parent)
        A.__init__(self, parent)


class B(AMixin, QLine):
    def __init__(self, parent) :
        AMixin.__init__(self, parent)
        QLine.__init__(self, parent)

class C(B):
    def __init__(self, parent) :
        B.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setLine(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Now `C` and `A` have the relationship you (probably) want, but `C` only has one `QObject` ancestor, so everything is good.